# Encountered with [ EXP-00056: ORACLE error 1017 encountered ] error while hitting the command expo build:android in command line f

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cmd, passwords, expo

I am creating my first react native app using expo client ,  when am hitting the  expo build:android  command on cmd  its asking for username and password .
After entering the right username and password , its giving this message :-

```
>EXP-00056: ORACLE error 1017 encountered
>ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>EXP-00005: all allowable logon attempts failed
>EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
```

I am logged in with same username and password  in  another cmd with the help of
following command :

> expo login -u username -p password

I am 100% sure that my credentials are right. I have no idea what's going wrong.

Please suggest what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hei I found the answer in this link for a similar issue I had... https://forums.expo.io/t/building-standalone-apps/937/14

Seems you as I have an oracle instance in your machine. That oracle has an "exp". As khilwanikaran says:

> app\UserName\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN
>   Here you will find an exe file as exp.exe
>   rename it and then try again